# My items aren't aligning in a row with flex / not mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox

I need my items in two rows, the `h3` and list as one row, and the video in a second row.

The h3 and lists are on the top row and the video below. Also when I inspect it's not mobile responsive on the phone / tablet setting.

```css
.features section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
}


h3{
  position: static;
  height: 47px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 130%;  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #262424;
  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 0px 24px
```

```html
<div class="bg-white overflow-hidden">
  <div class="features">
    <div class="flex relative max-w-screen-xl mx-auto py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <section>
        <h3 class="flex-1"> Features</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Easy group conversation </li>
          <li>Free movement</li>
          <li>Emojo</li>
          <li>Private messages</li>
          <li>Presenting</li>
          <li>Tags</li>
        </ul>
        <video class="flex-2" width=869px height="346px" autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in the code itself...

- Check your width attribute on the video (there are no quotes around
  the amount, maybe that's affecting something).
- Also, your first CSS selector says `.features section`, but there is
  no `<section>` tag so either add a section tag that you want to
  style or remove it from the CSS selector.
- Generally, your list items should be inside of an unordered list
  element `<ul>`.
- Also, there is an unclosed div in the example code (but I realise
  that may just be an example).
- In your H3 styling you    have `display:    flex` and then `flex: none`.

I think it would be easier to put the elements that you want on each row inside of their own div that is then styled as flex-row.
You can then choose how to style them within each row.

(unless you're using something like Bootstrap, in which case there is an easier way).

My favourite CSS flexbox cheat sheet is this...
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Also, I popped a suggestion onto codepen, maybe it'll help.

https://codepen.io/petermanchester1987/pen/KKMrOeG

Peter Manchester

Answer (score 0):

Just add a break, this is a simple `div` with the below CSS properties applied to it. This also forces you to add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the flex parent.

Anytime you want the next set of elements to be on the new row add `<div class="break"></div>` before those elements.

You can add `justify-content: space-between;` to make the video next to the feature list be spaced evenly within your page, although not necessary (it will appear right next to the list without it).

```css
.features section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Add this for breaks to work */
  width: 100%;
  /* justify-content: space-between;  Distribute items evenly on each row */
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.video {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
  <div>
    <section>
      <h3>Features</h3>
      <div class="break"></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Easy group conversation </li>
        <li>Free movement</li>
        <li>Emojo</li>
        <li>Private messages</li>
        <li>Presenting</li>
        <li>Tags</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="video">VIDEO GOES HERE</div>
      <!-- Replace this with your video element -->
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, your video element is missing `" "` on the width attribute.

Comment: Hi, this is nearly what I need but the video needs to be to the right of the list. So a two column container.

Comment: What flex element is best to achieve this?

Comment: @ElektraMurphy just remove the last `break`, and the video will be next to the list.

Comment: @ElektraMurphy check latest edit, see if that is what you want

Comment: Thanks, there's something wrong with my code because its still not working. Must be something in the code somewhere!

Comment: @ElektraMurphy remove `flex-flow: row` from `.features section`

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful!